# Views Row template not loaded

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views

I am working on a drupal 7 Site using Views 3

Following situation:

I have created my view and get this theme suggestions

[image]

As you can see I created a --presse-page.tpl.php file bold marked in the second block, it works fine, but I need to style only the rows. So I created a views-view-fields--presse.tpl.php file, but if I rescan the theme, it does not appears.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your file name should be one of the one's suggested to you by views. I don't see the name you chose under the section "Row Style Output" in the views output. The best file name in that list would probably be **"--presse-page.tpl.php"**. Change the file to that name and then rescan.